Errors porting ReactNative project to web
I have a small react native project that I am trying to port to web. I'm using react-app-rewired and have hit some errors after trying to make placeholders for components for those that aren't available for web.
In my config-overrides.js i'm mapping an alias to these placeholders, but i'm getting the following errors (all similar looks like they aren't being correctly imported) when I try to run it:
Any help or pointers would be appreciated TYA
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/MapMarkerNativeComponent.js 12:48-113

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/codegenNativeCommands' in '/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib'

